# install4j on Mac: "Open PDF Viewer" action causes UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: macos, pdf, install4j

Using install4j 6.1.3 on Kubuntu, I am developing installers for Windows, Linux, Mac.

On Mac 10.11 I am try to display a PDF file using the "Open PDF viewer" action. However, I am getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError as shown below. May it be that install4j has trouble loading a native library?

Thanks,
Jens

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: apple.laf.JRSUIControl.getCFDictionary(Z)J
    at apple.laf.JRSUIControl.getCFDictionary(Native Method)
    at apple.laf.JRSUIControl.<init>(JRSUIControl.java:102)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.<init>(AquaPainter.java:135)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter.create(AquaPainter.java:44)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaSplitPaneDividerUI.<init>(AquaSplitPaneDividerUI.java:43)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaSplitPaneUI.createDefaultDivider(AquaSplitPaneUI.java:48)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI.installDefaults(BasicSplitPaneUI.java:332)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI.installUI(BasicSplitPaneUI.java:316)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:666)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.setUI(JSplitPane.java:374)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.updateUI(JSplitPane.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(JSplitPane.java:356)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(JSplitPane.java:285)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(JSplitPane.java:266)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder.buildUtilityAndDocumentSplitPane(SwingViewBuilder.java:1635)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder.buildContents(SwingViewBuilder.java:487)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder.buildViewerPanel(SwingViewBuilder.java:470)
    at com.install4j.extensions.pdf.ShowPdfAction.showPdf(ShowPdfAction.java:71)
    at com.install4j.extensions.pdf.ShowPdfAction.execute(ShowPdfAction.java:53)
    at com.install4j.extensions.pdf.ShowPdfAction.install(ShowPdfAction.java:42)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$7.executeAction(ContextImpl.java:1668)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$7.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1659)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$7.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1656)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(FetchObjectAction.java:14)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionDirect(HelperCommunication.java:272)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionInt(HelperCommunication.java:247)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionChecked(HelperCommunication.java:185)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.fetchObjectChecked(HelperCommunication.java:168)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performActionIntStatic(ContextImpl.java:1656)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.performActionInt(InstallerContextImpl.java:151)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performAction(ContextImpl.java:1103)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeAction(Controller.java:368)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Controller.java:334)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:195)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:59)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher.main(MacLauncher.java:67)
```

Comment: That native library is part of the JRE and loaded by the JRE, not by install4j. What JRE do you use? Have to tried using a JRE bundle in install4j?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ingo, I am using a "Mac OS X folder" type media file, and bundle a "Macosx (amd64) 1.8.0_102" JRE. I don't know whether that is important or not, but the Mac system also has its own Java JRE installation (1.8.0_65). Any ideas on how to track this down?

Comment: I think I have found the bug, please contact me at support@ej-technologies.com to get a current build of install4j.